# WordNet - Multiple relationships possible between two words?

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet

Can there be more tha one relationship (SYNONYMS, HOLONYM, etc) between two words in WordNet? Logically, I would say no but with different senses, is it possible?

Comment: Maybe. Why this is important for you any ways? [Perhaps you can post it on "Linguistics Stack Exchange" to get an answer.]

Comment: I want to get the most 'concrete' relationship that WordNet can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't get that from WordNet. You need context for that purpose and there is no context in WordNet. You can try [Roget's](http://www.nzdl.org/ELKB/) which has some sort of conceptual taxonomy of words [starting from abstract concepts and becoming more specific], but in terms of coverage it's no where near WordNet. Perhaps you would require to look into [ESA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_semantic_analysis) which provides a similarity metric based on Wikipedia. Also, have a look at the popular [word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/).